# python job scheduling- job() missing 1 required positional argument: 'soup'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, jobs, schedule

## soup object as argument?

```
def make_soup(url):
  thepage =  urlopen(url)
  soupdata = BS(thepage, "html.parser")
  return soupdata


def job():
  #Call soup function
  soup = make_soup("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MRK?p=MRK")
  span = soup.find('div',{'class':"My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)"}).find('span').text

  span = float(span)
  return span

schedule.every(1).minutes.do(job)

while True:
  schedule.run_pending()
  time.sleep(1)
```

## TypeError: job() missing 1 required positional argument: 'soup'

Comment: try `schedule.every(1).minutes.do(job())` instead?

Comment: <ipython-input-481-b052a493870e> in <module>()
      6   return span
      7 
----> 8 schedule.every(1).minutes.do(job())
      9 
     10 while True:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py in do(self, job_func, *args, **kwargs)
    438         :return: The invoked job instance
    439         """
--> 440         self.job_func = functools.partial(job_func, *args, **kwargs)
    441         try:
    442             functools.update_wrapper(self.job_func, job_func)

TypeError: the first argument must be callable

Comment: sorry for all the code,i just cant figure it out for the life of me,i got it to work before,not sure what I did wrong now

Comment: I tried with your code , no such error,   can you post full code

Comment: posted @xiaoming

Comment: Still Confused why it does not work

Comment: it's ok that I run this code on my pc,  is this all your code or just combine some snippet together to post, I guest may be the job method is not the one you expected, pls post this result before schedule,  ```python import inspect
print(inspect.getmodule(job))
print(inspect.getsource(job))```